# Passing Cookie using Web.Contents in PowerBI Desktop

Tags: cookies, powerbi, m, powerbi-desktop

I have API which authenticates a user based on Cookies. API basically uses PHP Sessions. I am looking for a method to pass a cookie to the WEB API which will then respond with JSON Data.

I am using below code to pass cookies.

```
= Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://myapp.example.com/api/test.php", [Headers=[Cookie="PHPSESSID:123abc"]]))
```

But the above code does not work.
Can you please help in finding out what I am doing wrong?

Reference: [`Web.Contents()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query-bi/m/web-contents)

Comment: What does it mean "does not work"? Try `Text.FromBinary` instead of `Json.Document`. Btw, are you sure you need GET? Maybe POST method? Your code looks ok. But is it ok on server-side?